# How to make RDP window restored from within powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have RDP connection opened and minimised or in  background. I want to restore / make it active.

When I tried this with notepad it is working, it is restoring it, but rdp window I can not catch.
I started by checking opened windows

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle, name, id
```

And it gives me back mstsc as rdp process, but when I tried to put it in script it doesn't work.
and if I change it to notepad it is working (if notepad is opened)
I have to give credits for this code to  Bobmccoy at community.spiceworks.com.

```
function Set-WindowStyle {
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 
                 'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED', 
                 'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
    $Style = 'SHOW',
    [Parameter()]
    $MainWindowHandle = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle
)
    $WindowStates = @{
        FORCEMINIMIZE   = 11; HIDE            = 0
        MAXIMIZE        = 3;  MINIMIZE        = 6
        RESTORE         = 9;  SHOW            = 5
        SHOWDEFAULT     = 10; SHOWMAXIMIZED   = 3
        SHOWMINIMIZED   = 2;  SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
        SHOWNA          = 8;  SHOWNOACTIVATE  = 4
        SHOWNORMAL      = 1
    }
    Write-Verbose ("Set Window Style {1} on handle {0}" -f $MainWindowHandle, $($WindowStates[$style]))

    $Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type –memberDefinition @” 
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
    public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
“@ -name “Win32ShowWindowAsync” -namespace Win32Functions –passThru

    $Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($MainWindowHandle, $WindowStates[$Style]) | Out-Null
}

(Get-Process -Name mstsc).MainWindowHandle | foreach { Set-WindowStyle MINIMIZE $_ }
(Get-Process -Name mstsc).MainWindowHandle | foreach { Set-WindowStyle RESTORE $_ }
```

This code works  if in last 2 sentence put notepad. I have to minimize it first because it wont restore if it is in background. But it doesn't work with rdp (mstsc) process.

Comment: This sounds environmental on your end, vs something PowerShell specific, as I use the type of thing, as well, and tested what you posted, and it works regardless of app I use. Now, what you are not saying, what OS and PowerShell version are you doing this on. My tests are all on Win10 1809 w/PSv5x and WS2K12R2 w/PSv4x.